# How to select latest rows from approver table

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to select latest row from approver table based on a request id.
Also i need to join request table and approver table based on request id

Tried latest() method but it will return only last record. But i want to retrieve last last row of each request id.

Tried group by and distinct but not worked. Could you please suggest a better way

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: `latest()` does not _return_ records, it orders them.

Comment: Please share what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two way to do this :

1. code a loop and get rows by a query for each row.
2. try this code :

   \DB::table('my_table')->selectRaw('*,max(id) as last')->groupBy('user_id')->get();

Answer (score 1):

maybe this would be work, use orderBy('column_name',desc)->first()

Comment: `->first()` will return _one_ record only, not what OP wants

Comment: use ->get() it will return all records max to min which column you used to orderBy. If you want last record of each requested ids used groupBy('column')->orderBy('column','desc')->get()

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
$last_approver = Approver::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    select * from approver where request_id = <your request id> order by <some column like created_at> limit 1
```